Why golang pointer can directly get object's properties
I'm using the golang pointer to do some empty check. But I'm so confused about how to check the nil situation. It's much different from C. For example there is a mock object
type Node struct {
    Val  int
    Next *Node
}

When I create object
a := &Node{Val:1,Next:nil}

And I want to judge if the a's next value is empty. I use the following code
if *a.Next == nil{}

But the complier raise error that the type is not align. Does it not mean the object (referred by a point)'s Next property? After I wrapped the *a with () it works. So I don't know why the * operator is not work.
Another question is that when I use the following
if a.Next == nil {}

It also works fine. But it is strange. Since a should refer to a memory address value which contains object. Memory address can't have "Next" property, only object has it. So why the a.Next can get the value instead of raising exception?
feel confused.

pointers to structs are automatically dereferenced when accessing fields, so you don't need to dereference the pointer explicitly.  use like if a.Next == nil

Also mentioned in the Tour of Go


if *a.Next == nil{}

But the complier raise error that the type is not align. Does it not mean the object (referred by a point)'s Next property? After I wrapped the *a with () it works. So I don't know why the * operator is not work.

Because *a.Next means *(a.Next), not (*a).Next. If you mean the latter, you would have to write so explicitly... if Go creators didn't think it was annoying, and put in the exception that forms the second part of your question:

Another question is that when I use the following
if a.Next == nil {}

It also works fine. But it is strange. Since a should refer to a memory address value which contains object. Memory address can't have "Next" property, only object has it. So why the a.Next can get the value instead of raising exception?

From Spec (Selectors):


As an exception, if the type of x is a defined pointer type and (*x).f is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is shorthand for (*x).f.


So, (*a).Next can be written a.Next without ambiguity.
Remember that while Go is descended from C, it does not mean its semantics is the same as C.

What you have here is a selector expression: a.Next is shorthand for (*a).Next and is of type *Node, so it's a pointer and you can directly compare it to nil. ``
*a.Next is a shorthand for *(*a).Next and of type Node, so you can't compare it to nil.
